# Cookies filtered out only in chrome

Tags: cookies

I have a chrome extension which use Oauth to authenticate users. This authentication create cookies which are shared to detect authentication on my other applications.
So when i'm authenticated by oAuth on my extension, i can go on another app and then if i refresh i'm connected without getting login process. This because cookies created by my OAuth process are shared and detected on others app.
This works fine on browser like Mozilla or Opera but don't works on Chrome cause cookies are filtered out with that info message :
this cookie was blocked because its path was not an exact match for or a super directory of the request url's path.(shown on screen by cookies with question mark (AUTH and KEYCLOAK prefixes)
[Cookies with AUTH and KEYCLOAK on yellow are filtered out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NyS9H.png)

How could i manage Chrome to accept those cookies ? But more, how could i manage this programmatically on request which have created cookies cause i can't tell my users to modify their Chrome configuration ?